# Can I get MySQL "Serialization failure: 1213 (Deadlock)" without a Transaction and on Single Rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a "Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock;". However, I've scanned my code (this is a Laravel app) and cannot find any use of transactions within the code path.

As far as I can tell, I'm not doing any table locking and I'm not using transactions. And (again - as far as I can tell) I am only updating single rows - I don't have multi-row deletes or truncates on my table.

Assuming this is true, under what conditions would this error be raised, assuming single selects and updates are being performed on single rows? Can it still occur?

Here is my "SHOW INNODB STATUS" output:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
170914  8:09:36
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 163BF1D7, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 467566, OS thread handle 0x7f3cd40c6700, query id 1484970989 
localhost wwwperson Updating
update `fmccache` set `dirty` = '1' where station_id = '3757' and vendor_id = '2' and operation_id = '1'
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 36364 n bits 128 index 
`fmccache_vendor_id_foreign` of table `database`.`fmccache` trx id 163BF1D7 
lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fc7; asc       ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 163BF1D6, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 3, locked 3
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 17 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 467565, OS thread handle 0x7f3c43aa5700, query id 1484970990 
localhost wwwperson Updating
update `fmccache` set `dirty` = '1' where station_id = '3653' and vendor_id = '2' and operation_id = '1'
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 36364 n bits 128 index `fmccache_vendor_id_foreign` of table `database`.`fmccache` trx id 163BF1D6 
lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 4 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fc7; asc       ;;

Record lock, heap no 5 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fc8; asc       ;;

Record lock, heap no 9 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fcc; asc       ;;

Record lock, heap no 10 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fcd; asc       ;;

Record lock, heap no 13 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fd0; asc       ;;

Record lock, heap no 14 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fd1; asc       ;;

Record lock, heap no 15 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
1: len 6; hex 000000007fd2; asc       ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 36362 n bits 136 index `GEN_CLUST_INDEX` of 
table `database`.`fmccache` trx id 163BF1D6 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 15 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
0: len 6; hex 000000007fd2; asc       ;;
1: len 6; hex 0000163436bf; asc    46 ;;
2: len 7; hex 5e0000202c0818; asc ^   ,  ;;
3: len 4; hex 00000ead; asc     ;;
4: len 4; hex 00000002; asc     ;;
5: len 4; hex 80000002; asc     ;;
6: len 8; hex 000000000000f03f; asc        ?;;
7: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1652B9A3
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1652B21D undo n:o < 0
History list length 3317
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 484099, OS thread handle 0x7f3c439e1700, query id 1540210787 
localhost root
SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS
```

Comment: With Innodb, every statement is a transaction but I don't suspect your issue is related to transactions. Can you share the output of ```SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS```?

Comment: Bill, I wish - the error only happens very rarely and I can't get that output during times of the error. Or is this report cumulative?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be and shows the last detected deadlocks.

Comment: Ok, just posted my innodb status. That was super helpful (thanks so much). So now my question comes down to "It appears that no transaction was occurring but should I remove the foriegn keys on that table to avoid this?"

Comment: Also found this SO post and bug fix that describes the problem (and a bug report), though they actually use transactions to reproduce - where I do not https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253291/1620112

Comment: Deadlocks are hard to diagnose without having the ability to debug the application layer along with the database It could be an indexing issue, long running queries, too many concurrent updates on the same data, etc etc. Check out this link to help learn how to debug these sorts of things. Good luck! https://hackernoon.com/troubleshooting-and-avoiding-deadlocks-mysql-rails-766913f3cfbc